# Background image clipped to draggable div

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, draggable

i'm trying to make this thing where i have a div with a full background image and a div on top with a container, and this div is draggable, and when dragged it shows the same image as the background but altered.

Well, something among the lines of this [pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/evbZgv)

My CSS so far:

```
.contain{
    position:relative;
}

#dummy{ 
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/CxYGDBq.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#dummy2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:99;
    left:0;
}

.mao{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/UbNyhzS.png);
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:999;
    background-size:contain;
}

.screen{
    width:960px;
    height:995px;
    background-color:pink;
    position:relative;
    left:32px;
    top:30px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/yjR8SCL.jpg);

}
```

Comment: The link in the question is dead... Do you happen to still have the code? It would be nice to add a runnable snippet to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can do this by finding the current position of the draggable object as it moves, and then using those values to set the `background-position` of the `screen`'s background, giving a sort of x-ray glasses effect.

```
var imageOffset = {
    top: 30,
    left: 32
};

$(function() {
    var screenHeight = $('body').height() - 300; // 300: moa height

    $(".screen").css('background-position', -(imageOffset.left) + 'px ' + -(screenHeight + imageOffset.top) + 'px');

    $(".mao").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(".screen").css('background-position', -(ui.position.left + imageOffset.left) + 'px ' + -(ui.position.top + imageOffset.top) + 'px');
        }
    });
})
```

Example Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWxwzK?editors=0000

You can also use the same piece of code to constrain the hand to the left/right boundaries of the screen. There's an example of code to do that in the official docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Comment: If this is not what you want feel free to let me know what's missing and I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

For what I assume you want to do I've edited your pen to reflect the proper changes. You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/tremayne_stewart/pen/EWrOEd).

**Improper Nesting** 
First thing changed was switching the div you wanted draggable `<div class="mao"></div>` to be a child of the `<div class="screen"></div>` element.

**CSS Image URLs** 
Just another thing to look out for - when specifying a URL in CSS you need to wrap it within quotation marks. These **"** $url_here **"**.